# AJAX запрос к 192.168.1.1

Tags: javascript, php, apache

возник такой вопрос!

У меня есть роутер netis могу ли я с помощью JS совершить AJAX запрос по адресу http://192.168.1.1/cgi-bin-igd/netcore_get.cgi в данном файле JSON с параметрами роутера с которыми работает frontend админки посылая POST запрос в данный файл. Абсолютно любой клиент из браузера подключенный к моей локальной сети может получить доступ к данному файлу без проблем. Но попытки отправить AJAX по данному адресу вызывают такое предупреждение:

- Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://192.168.1.1/?callback=jQuery34109244564068791703_1582834223063&_=1582834223064 with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

Хочу понять возможен ли такой сценарий, пользователь переходит по ссылке на абсолютно любой сторонний сервер получает JS с этого Web сервера который в свою очередь сделает AJAX запрос к роутеру и сможет каким либо образом манипулировать этими данными.

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: 1) относительно аякса на левый сервер - есть ограничения на кроссдоменные запросы. если сервер не выставляет соответствующие заголовки, то получите ошибку.  2) все аякс запросы можно заменить на не-аякс запросы. 3) чтобы какой-то пользователь находясь на каком-то любом стороннем сервере мог сделать запрос к вашему роутеру вам нужен глобальный маршутизируемый ip-адрес, к коим 192.168.1.1 явно не относится. Но если у вас и есть белый IP, то вероятность того, что роутер отдаст что-либо по внешнему интерфейсу близка к нулю. В общем, с этим адресом вы можете взаимодейстовать только у себя дома.

Comment: а хотя у вас написано про локальную сеть. Вообще проверьте, что post запрос на изменение можно отправить 1) без авторизации в админке 2) при подключении без провода (т.е. по wifi)